# PCL Rigid Transformation using IterativeClosestPoint - Error: vector erase iterator outside range

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, qt, computer-vision, point-clouds

I am currently trying to calculate rigid transformation between two point sets so I tried to use the code given by the tutorial on pointclouds.org:

http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/iterative_closest_point.php#iterative-closest-point

For my case I only changed the part where the data is randomly generated to something that loads the point data I want to analyze. Everything else is exactly like in the tutorial...
(I also tried testing exactly the tutorial code with the random data, in case I had somethign wrong with reading my input data)

Since I work with Qt I integrated the PCL library, Eigen library and FLANN library to my project. It finds all headers and successfully compiles with MSVC 2008...

Unfortunately I always get a runtime error at

```
icp.setInputTarget(cloud_out);
```

saying:

> Debug Assertion failed! Program:
>   ...*MSVC2008*_Qt_SDK_Release\release\Project.exe File: c:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft VIsual Studio 10.0\CV\include\vector Line: 1200
>
> Expression: vector erase iterator outside range
>
> [..] ... check documentation ... [..]

Does anybody know what that means? The input clouds both have the same size and have filled values.

I would be thankful for any help!

**UPDATE 1:**

The error message shows some file path for MSVC 2010 (10.0) ... So I tried to uninstall Visual Studio 2010 since I don't really need it. But still, if I compile in Debug mode, it shows me an error message, but with `Expression: vector iterators incompatible` instead... If I now run it in Release mode, it just crashes at runtime (at the same line), but doesn't show that error message.

Comment: What is `icp` and `cloud_out`?  It's not showing a debug assertion message when compiled in Release mode, because the debug assertions are only handled in a Debug compilation.

Comment: Have you tried running it in debugger and finding which line of yours triggers it?

Comment: cloud_out is the point cloud that should be matched. Look at the tutorial line 10. icp is the instance of the IterativeClosestPoint class (line 37).
Well I tried to debug it but I couldn't get an information out of that since I can't set stop points or anything. Just seeing the output of the debugger or disassembler didn't help at all...

But isn't it weird taht it even tries to get some information from the VC 10.0 path? I mean after I uninstalled it, there isn't even a C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 anymore...

Comment: Your debugger should provide you with a stack trace so you can find the last call that has source code.  Also have you done a clean compile after uninstalling VS10.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems so be a problem with the library you use. Assuming you have done a clean build, checked your PATH variable and everything and that Visual Studio 2010 is removed, this might be a problem with the library itself. Are you you using the right one?

The current Qt SDK has MSVC2008 in it, so I guess it takes everything from where it needs. But either the compiler in Qt or one of the libraries you use that might want the 2010 version...

Hope it helps!